# Scala makeString + pre + sep + post with foldLeft

Tags: scala

so I would like to create a string like "[a-to-b]"
def my func

```
def makeString(xs: List[String], pre : String, sep: String, post: String) : String =xs match{
case Nil => ""
case head::tail =>  xs.foldLeft(pre)((r,e) => r + sep + e) + post }
```

scala > makeString(List("a","to","b"), "[","-","]")

but it turned outString = [a-to-b-]

How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've already extracted `head` and `tail`, you might as well use them for your `foldLeft` (instead of `pre` and `xs`) and put `pre` and `post` outside it.

```scala
def makeString(xs: List[String], pre : String, sep: String, post: String): String =
  xs match {
    case Nil => ""
    case head::tail =>  pre + tail.foldLeft(head)((r,e) => r + sep + e) + post
  }
```

[Example Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/a8aDHntURtOAlxyW0J2iQA)